# Windows 10 turns off abruptly whenever AC power cable is unplugged

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have 2 problems.

1. Whenever I unplug my power cable, or when there is a power failure, Windows immediately shuts down.
2. Unable to work without a connected power supply. If I try to turn on my computer without power supply (only with battery), Windows tries to boot, but the display turns black and shuts down.

The model is Dell Inspiron N4050. I have checked my battery. It is fine.

Comment: how have you checked that the battery is fine? this looks like the battery is damaged

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that your battery is fine (e.g. you have tried it on another laptop and it works) then the problem is your laptop.
But from the description you wrote it looks like a battery problem: did you already try to install the diagnostic program aulauncher.exe provided by Dell here? http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14-intel-n4050/drivers
Please also note Dell's site disclaimer for N4050: "Product not tested for Windows 10 upgrade
Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product. If you choose to upgrade, some features, applications, and connected devices may not work as expected."

Answer (score 0):

recently had similar problem,  nothing had changed besides an update to microsoft..  turns out reading forum from http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1632945/notebook-shuts-unplugging-power-source.html   found solution that worked for me..

had to turn off the power service ,  problem solved.

Comment: Consider adding some quoted reference to this answer supporting what you state in case the link ever dies so the answer content is still available that is currently only available via that link per your suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't help at all